# Jhipster : disable dialog close on submit

Tags: jhipster

I am using Jhipster V3.
I have created an entity, and Jhipster generated all the needed views.
My client wants that in the update dialog of this entity, the click on Save doesn't close the popup.
I have commented one line on this function :

```
var onSaveSuccess = function (result) {
    $scope.$emit('rhTechvalleyApp:consultantUpdate', result);
    //$uibModalInstance.close(result);
    vm.isSaving = false;
};
```

In this popup I have a datepicker component. Its value is getting blank once the save process has finished. It s only a display issue, but I don't know how to get rid of it.

If anyone knows...

Thanks.

**[UPDATE]**

```
transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    data.dateEnregistrement = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.dateEnregistrement);
                    data.dateDernierPointDisponibilite = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.dateDernierPointDisponibilite);
                    data.dateDisponibilite = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.dateDisponibilite);
                    return data;
                }

<div class="input-group"> 
    <input id="field_dateEnregistrement" type="text" class="form-control" name="dateEnregistrement" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateformat}}" ng-model="vm.consultant.dateEnregistrement" is-open="vm.datePickerOpenStatus.dateEnregistrement"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openCalendar('dateEnregistrement')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `transformResponse` to the `update` function of the Angular service for your entity. It should be the same as `transformResponse` for `get`.

Example:

```
'update': {
    method:'PUT',
    transformResponse: function (data) {
        data = angular.fromJson(data);
        data.birthDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.birthDate);
        return data;
    }
}
```

The reason you need to do this is because the server will return a string like `2016-04-12` for dates. This needs to be converted to a JavaScript `Date` object, which is what Angular expects for `type="date"` inputs. If you use a string instead of a date object for `ngModel` on a `date` input, Angular will throw an error and fail to fill the field. You can use `DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer` for LocalDate and `DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer` for DateTime.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the same transformResponse as in the GET method  (see update), the dates are well set. But in the datetimepicker input, I am still getting a blank value

Comment: I forgot to mention, do the same for the save method.